# Brand new Pokemon Cards bent in packaging!

Tags: playing-cards, pokemon

I just opened my new Enchanted Echo starter deck and found two fairy energy cards bent in the box! These cards are completely unusable and buying this deck was primarily for getting the fairy energy cards! Im outraged! Is there any way that I can contact the Pokemon Trading Card company and file a formal complaint and maybe try for a refund, or do I need to talk to the store I bought it from? The cards were bent in the unopened packaging, so this is a defect. I can't find any information on the Pokemon Trading Card company though! Does anyone know where I should file my complaint?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can pokemon be played with card sleeves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Pokemon.com FAQ](http://support.pokemon.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=15227&redirect=true)

> **My cards were ruined, can you replace them?**
>
> Company policy dictates that we only replace products damaged through manufacturer error. In addition, we do not keep inventory of individual cards here, and are unable to offer 'card for card' replacements. We recommend that you try to return your purchase to the retailer if your cards are damaged for any reason other than manufacturing error.
>
> If you feel your cards were damaged or altered due to a manufacturing error please scan each card in question front and back and send in a ticket to prodhelp@pokemon.com with your first and last name, your proof of purchase, your date of birth, and address.

Comment: that sucks. I definitely threw away my receipt. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you are friendly with your store they may be able to provide you with another copy of your proof of purchase.